# QGIS installation error Qt versions OSX

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I am trying to install QGIS 2.14 in OSX El Capitan using brew and osgeo/osgeo4mac repository. But when I tried to install it I got the following error

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1328 (message):
Found unsuitable Qt version "5.6.1" from /usr/local/opt/qt5/bin/qmake, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:272 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Apparently there is a problem in version used for Qt 5, I have Qt4 also installed but qgis installation has dependencies of package qt5 so it installs it anyway.

What I tried so far:

- Use --ignore-dependecy qt5 flag, but nothing happens, no installation and no error
- Make a symbolic link through qmake files, but get the same error

I have recently installed QGIS in another OSX device with no problems